# Сравнение скорости

Tags: php, sql

Быстрее ли этот вариант?

```
mysql_query("SELECT id, login, password FROM users LIMIT 1");
```

Или этот? И почему

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 1");
mysql_query("SELECT login FROM users LIMIT 1");
mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Разумеется быстрее первое. время выборки одной записи примерно одинакова. Если вы ее 3 раза выбираете то и времени затрачиваете в 3 раза больше

Comment: Что быстрее - на машине перевезти сразу 3 пассажиров или по 1 пассажиру за раз? То же самое - машине практически неважно в этом случае, 1 или 3 пассажира за раз везти.

Comment: Кстати, первый вариант гарантирует, что значения всех трёх полей будут взяты для одной и той же записи. В то время как второй вариант - что с отдельными запросами,- запросто может дать значения из разных записей.

Comment: В дополнение к вышесказанному, нет гарантии (при именно таких запросах), что полученные во втором варианте `id`, `login` и `password` будут каким-либо образом связаны.

Comment: @Akina опередил :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сравнения выполнения различных скриптов, в php есть функция mixed microtime ([ bool $get_as_float = false ] ).
Если $get_as_float установлен в TRUE, то microtime() возвратит результат в вещественном виде (float), представляющий собой текущее время в секундах, прошедших с начала Эпохи Unix с точностью до микросекунд.
В начало скрипта пишите

```
$start = microtime(true);
```

Вконце скрипта пишите

```
$end = microtime(true) - $start;
```

На выходе секунды!